# Como utilizar Xcode 5.0 com 10.7.5?

Tags: osx, xcode

Tenho um portátil macbook que não posso instalar o último sistema operativo OSX - Mavericks (informação da Apple), mas preciso instalar o XCode 5.0 para desenvolvimento de aplicações em iOS7. Por isso preciso de ajuda para saber:

Como instalar o Xcode 5.0 no OS 10.7.5?

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível instalar na sua versão do Mac OS (10.7.5), já que versão mínima para executar o Xcode 5 é a 10.8.4.

Ou você utiliza o Xcode 4 (na qual não é possível desenvolver para IOS 7), ou atualiza o seu Mac OS.